# Python turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I'm currently new to python programming. Nowadays I'm building a snake game using the turtle module. I want to refresh the screen after every piece of snake object parts has moved. So I turned off the tracer and use the update function after the for loop.

But to do that I must import the time module and use the time.sleep() function.If I don't use it the python turtle module begins to not respond. I want to know what is the reason why I must use the time function and why I can't simply use sc.update directly without time function.

here is my code

```
from turtle import *
from snake import *
import time

sc = Screen()
sc.bgcolor('black')
sc.setup(width=600, height=600)
sc.tracer(0)

# diyego is our snake name
diyego = Snake(10)

run = 1
while run:
#here is the problem 
    sc.update()
    time.sleep(1) #used time.sleep
    for i in range(len(diyego.snake_object_list)-1, 0, -1):
        infront_item_position = diyego.snake_object_list[i - 1].pos()
        diyego.snake_object_list[i].goto(infront_item_position)

    diyego.snake_head.forward(10)


sc.exitonclick()




#Snake module

from turtle import *


class Snake():
    def __init__(self, number_of_parts):
        """Should pass the lenght of snake"""
        self.snake_object_list = []
        self.create_snake_parts(number_of_parts)
        self.snake_head = self.snake_object_list[0]

    def create_snake_parts(self, number_of_parts):
        """ Get number of parts which snake shuld have and create snake it"""
        x_cor = 0
        for i in range(number_of_parts):
            snake = Turtle()
            snake.speed(0)
            snake.shape("circle")
            snake.color('white')
            snake.penup()
            snake.setx(x=x_cor)
            self.snake_object_list.append(snake)
            x_cor += -20
```

I just want to know why the turtle gets not respond when I remove the time.sleep()

Comment: What happens when you reduce the time to lower and lower amounts ?  `time.sleep(0.5)` , `time.sleep(0.1)`, `time.sleep(0.05)` etc etc

Comment: Perhaps reduce it to the lowest acceptable amount.

Comment: It increase the speed of my snake.

Comment: Which is to be expected. That is what the time sleep is for. Any reason you want to remove the time ?

Comment: But sc.update() function should work with out the help of time.sleep() isn't it

Comment: I want to know why sc.update() function not working without the help of time.sleep(). Thanks for your reply dude

Comment: In other words, you want it to run extremely fast. So fast that it hardly has time to update before the next update is called.... hmm... are you sure you want that ?

Comment: Regardless - I don't actually know why.... I just know what I would do....

Comment: so basically, we use time.sleep to determine the interval between two slides

Comment: based on the code you are using - that is correct

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is possible, but the problem isn't lack of use of the `sleep()` function but rather your use of (effectively) `while True:` which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle.  Let's rework your code using `ontimer()` events and make the snake's basic movement a method of the snake itself:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

class Snake():
    def __init__(self, number_of_parts):
        """ Should pass the length of snake """
        self.snake_parts = []
        self.create_snake_parts(number_of_parts)
        self.snake_head = self.snake_parts[0]

    def create_snake_parts(self, number_of_parts):
        """ Get number of parts which snake should have and create snake """
        x_coordinate = 0

        for _ in range(number_of_parts):
            part = Turtle()
            part.shape('circle')
            part.color('white')
            part.penup()
            part.setx(x_coordinate)

            self.snake_parts.append(part)
            x_coordinate -= CURSOR_SIZE

    def move(self):
        for i in range(len(self.snake_parts) - 1, 0, -1):
            infront_item_position = self.snake_parts[i - 1].position()
            self.snake_parts[i].setposition(infront_item_position)

        self.snake_head.forward(CURSOR_SIZE)

def slither():
    diyego.move()
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(slither, 100)  # milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

diyego = Snake(10)

slither()

screen.exitonclick()
```